# Parse string date to millis in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I am using SDF to parse a string date to millis with below code

```
private fun dateToMilliseconds(dateValue: String): Long? {
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
val date: Date
try {
    date = sdf.parse(dateValue)!!
    return date.time
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
return null
}
```

And the date is `val pdt = "2024-01-17T20:14:29.819Z"`

On running it in android I get the exception for unparseable date

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2024-01-17T20"
```

Comment: Please for your sanity use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for your date and time work. `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` have severe design problems and are long outdated. I recommend you don’t touch them. See [the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77841698/5772882).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. From `println(dateToMilliseconds(pdt))` I get `1705518869819` and no exception. The output is not correct, though. The correct millisecond value for your string `pdt` is 1 705 522 469 819.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code in IntellijIdea and Android Studio and it works properly.
Make sure you imported below classes and not using other same name classes:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
```

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is a notorious troublemaker of a class and best completely forgotten. In my most honest opinion helping users with how to use it is doing them an ill favour.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

You can declare an optional pattern inside a `[]` with a `DateTimeFormatter`. In the following demo, you can see that a single `DateTimeFormatter` can parse all four strings.

After parsing the date-time string, you can convert the resulting `LocalDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime` in the system's timezone. In the final step, you convert the `ZonedDateTime` into an `Instant` and get from it the milliseconds since the epoch.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH[:mm[:ss[.SSS]]]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Stream.of(
                "2024-01-17T20",
                "2024-01-17T20:10",
                "2024-01-17T20:10:05",
                "2024-01-17T20:10:05.123"
        ).forEach(s -> {
            var ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf);
            var millis = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toInstant()
                            .toEpochMilli();
            System.out.println(ldt + " -> " + millis);
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2024-01-17T20:00 -> 1705521600000
2024-01-17T20:10 -> 1705522200000
2024-01-17T20:10:05 -> 1705522205000
2024-01-17T20:10:05.123 -> 1705522205123
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/g1oFbL)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
fun parseStringDateToMillis(dateString: String, pattern: String): Long {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
    val date = dateFormat.parse(dateString)
    return date?.time ?: 0L
}
```

use this function in an activity or fragment:

```
   val dateString = "2022-01-15T12:30:45"
   val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
   val millis = parseStringDateToMillis(dateString, pattern)

   println("Milliseconds: $millis")
```